# How to add event subscription to Azure storage using New-AzEventGridSubscription?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to add subscription to storage account using New-AzEventGridSubscription. The subscription should be triggered by blob modification in a container and put message to a certain queue. I created the following script:

```
$ResourceGroup = "test"
$includedEventTypes = "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated", "Microsoft.Storage.BlobDeleted"

New-AzEventGridSubscription `
-ResourceId "/subscriptions/[id]/resourceGroups/[group]/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/[name]" `
-EventSubscriptionName DummyName `
-Endpoint "/subscriptions/[id]/resourceGroups/[group]/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/[name]/queueServices/default/queues/my-queue" `
-ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup `
-EndpointType "storagequeue" `
-SubjectBeginsWith "prefix" `
-SubjectEndsWith "suffix"
```

but it throws an error:

```
New-AzEventGridSubscription : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzEventGridSubscription `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzEventGridSubscription], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventGrid.NewAzureEventGridSubscription
```

I made similar command to add subscription to a custom topic, which worked well:

```
New-AzEventGridSubscription `
    -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup `
    -EventSubscriptionName SubscriptionName `
    -TopicName MyCustomTopic `
    -EndpointType "storagequeue" `
    -Endpoint "/subscriptions/[id]/resourceGroups/[group]/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/[account]/queueServices/default/queues/my-queue" `
    -SubjectBeginsWith "prefix" `
    -SubjectEndsWith "suffix"
```

I tried several modifications, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After throwing out "ResourceGroup" parameter, reordering other parameters, and putting some arguments into variables, I *finally* managed to get my script up and running... If anyone ever needs similar stuff, here it is:

```
$subscriptionId = "<id>"
$ResourceGroup = "<group>"
$includedEventTypes = "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated", "Microsoft.Storage.BlobDeleted"
$storageAccount = "<account name>"
$endpoint = "/subscriptions/"+$subscriptionId+"/resourceGroups/"+$ResourceGroup+"/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/"+$storageAccount+"/queueServices/default/queues/my-queue"
$resourceId = "/subscriptions/"+$subscriptionId+"/resourceGroups/"+$ResourceGroup+"/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/"+$storageAccount
$subject = "prefix"

New-AzEventGridSubscription `
-EventSubscriptionName MySubscriptionName `
-Endpoint $endpoint `
-ResourceId $resourceId `
-EndpointType "storagequeue" `
-SubjectBeginsWith $subject `
-SubjectEndsWith "suffix" `
-IncludedEventType $includedEventTypes
```